# upload file only to unzip it without writing file on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my asp.net aplication I would like to give the oportunity to the user to check on its local machine zip file. Then I would like to get this file on server(without saving it on the server) unzip it proceed and save proceeded data to database.

What should I do to accomplish this task? Thank You for any hints

Answer (score 4):

I would use a zip library to read in the zip file stream and process the files contained inside.  I have previously used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) for this purpose before. See [SharpZipLib Examples](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx) for more information.